# Summing a single row vector by column in Octave

Tags: octave

I have written a short Octave script which draws the function `sum(sin(2k-1)/(2k-1))` for `k = 1..n` terms. (I am attempting to model how successive terms make the output converge to a square wave.

```
% Program to model square-wave using sum of sines

terms=3

theta=linspace(0, 6*pi, 1000);
k=[1:terms]';
n=2*k-1;

q=sin(n*theta)./n;
y=sum(q);
plot(theta, y);
```

It works OK (i.e. the `sum()` function returns a vector containing the sum of each column) for terms > 1. But when terms == 1 (i.e. it should just draw a sine wave) the `sum()` function computes the sum of the row and just returns a scalar.

How do I get the `sum()` function to total each column even if there is only one row or how do I reshape or slice or whatever the row vector such that rather than being a 1-dimensional vector of dimension *n* it effectively becomes a 2-dimensional matrix of dimension *1xn*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sum()`, like many other functions in Octave, will act on the first non-singleton dimension by default. So all you need to do is to be specific about the dimension. From `sum()` help text:

> If DIM is omitted, it defaults to the first non-singleton dimension.

So, all you need to do is be specific about the dimension, i.e., use `sum (q, 1)`:

```
terms = 1

theta = linspace (0, 6*pi, 1000);
k = [1:terms]';
n = 2*k-1;

q = sin (n*theta) ./ n;
y = sum (q, 1);
plot (theta, y);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
q=sin(n*theta)./n;
if (terms == 1)
    y = q;
else
    y=sum(q);
end
plot(theta, y);
```

See if that works.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm sure it *will* work, but it seems like a bit of a kludge. The program itself is neither here nor there. What I want to know (essentially) is how can I make a vector behave (and be treated as) a matrix.